# installing and using differential methylation DSS software

Tags: dss, differential-methylation

I am attempting to install and use the Bioconductor package DSS on Ubuntu 22.04.

Following the instructions here: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DSS.html

I get to this error:

```
hfile_libcurl.c:45:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory     
   45 | #include <curl/curl.h>                                                                                        
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                        
compilation terminated.                                                                                               
make[1]: *** [Makefile.Rhtslib:128: hfile_libcurl.o] Error 1                 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpNry6uq/R.INSTALL10673560786c68/Rhtslib/src/htslib-1.7'
make: *** [Makevars.common:24: htslib] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 22.04, install:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then reattempt:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("DSS")
```

Then upon completion:

```
library(DSS)
Loading required package: Biobase
Loading required package: BiocGenerics

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’                                                                                     

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:                                                                
                                                                                                                      
    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs                                                                                          
...
```